# Simple code compilation problems

Tags: java, compilation

```
import acm.program.*;

public class mainApp extends ConsoleProgram {
    public void run() {
        ////////////////////////
        Item aItems[] = new Item[26];
        aItems[1] = new Motherboard("970a", 2014, 200.0, "GIGABYTE", "INTEL", 64, 5);
        aItems[2] = new Motherboard("gb4", 2012, 150.0, "ASROCK", "AMD", 32, 4);
        aItems[3] = new Proccesor("I5", 2010, 180.0, "INTEL", 3.3, 4);
        aItems[4] = new Proccesor("I7", 2014, 900.0, "INTEL", 4.0, 4);
        aItems[5] = new Gcard("RADEON", 2012, 300.0, "GIGABYTE", "AMD", 4);
        aItems[6] = new Gcard("RADEON", 2010, 200.0, "SAPPHIRE", "NVIDIA", 2);
        aItems[7] = new Ram("IO", 2010, 100.0, "ASUS", "DDR", 4, 1600);
        aItems[8] = new Ram("LM", 2012, 160.0, "PALIT", "DDR3", 8, 2000);
        aItems[9] = new HardDrive("E2", 2013, 100.0, "WD", "SSD", 2.5, 750);
        aItems[10] = new HardDrive("LM", 2012, 150.0, "HP", "HDD", 3.5, 1000);
        aItems[11] = new Monitor("CFA90", 2014, 180.0, "SAMSUNG", "LCD", "23,5", "1080", "HDMI");
        aItems[12] = new Monitor("27EA", 2013, 280.0, "ASUS", "LED", "28", "1080", "HDMI");
        aItems[13] = new Mouse("Dethadder", 2013, 80.0, "Razer", "Optical", "wired");
        aItems[14] = new Mouse("M9Q", 2013, 80.0, "Microsoft", "laser", "wireless");
        aItems[15] = new Keyboard("Blackwidow", 2014, 130.0, "Razer", "wired");
        aItems[16] = new Keyboard("GK10", 2013, 100.0, "CM Storm", "wireless");
        aItems[17] = new Printer("PS3H", 2012, 90.0, "HP", "laser", "colored");
        aItems[18] = new Printer("SPP5", 2013, 190.0, "SAMSUNG", "inkjet", "black and white");


        ////////////////////////
        boolean flag = true;
        boolean flag1 = true;
        boolean flag2 = true;
        String sales[] = new String[5];
        String orders[] = new String[5];
        println("Welcome to our shop ");
        do {
            println("0 ) available products");
            println("1 ) overview orders ");
            println("2 ) overview sales ");
            println("3 ) make new order ");
            println("4 ) make new sale ");
            println("5 ) return ");
            int x = readInt("Click a number from 0-5 to choose what you want: ");
            /////////////////////// switch of x starts here
            switch (x) {
                case 0:
                    for (int i = 0; i <= 25; i++) {

                        if (aItems[i] != null) {
                            if (i = 0) {
                                println("MOTHERBOARDS:");
                            }
                            if (i = 2) {
                                println("PROCESSORS:");
                            }
                            if (i = 4) {
                                println("GRAPHICS CARDS:");
                            }
                            if (i = 6) {
                                println("RAM MEMORIES:");
                            }
                            if (i = 8) {
                                println("HARD DRIVES:");
                            }
                            if (i = 10) {
                                println("MONITORS:");
                            }
                            if (i = 12) {
                                println("MOUSES:");
                            }
                            if (i = 14) {
                                println("KEYBOARDS:");
                            }
                            if (i = 16) {
                                println("PRINTERS:");
                            }

                            println(aItems[i]);
                        }

                    }
                    break;


                case 4:
                    boolean flag3 = true;
                    while (flag3 == true) {
                        String kind2 = readLine("Do you want to sale hardware or peripheral product ? : ");


                        if (kind.equals("hardware")) {
                            String product = readLine("Do you want monitor ,mouse ,printer or keyboard ? : ");
                            if (product.equals("monitor")) {
                                println("We have 2 available monitors: ");

                            } else if (product.equals("mouse")) {
                            } else if (product.equals("printer")) {

                            } else if (product.equals("keyboard")) {
                            }
                            flag2 = false;
                        } else if (kind.equals("peripheral")) {

                            flag2 = false;
                        } else {
                            println("give the right type of product!!");
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                switch (b) {
                    case 0:
                        println("The available Motherboards are:");
                        println(aItems[1]);
                        println(aItems[2]);
                        println("Enter on for first motherboard and 2 for the second motherboard: ");
                        int c = readInt("Enter number: ");

                    case 5:
                        flag = false;
                        break;


                }

            }
            while (flag == true) ;
            println("Have a nice day !!!");

        }

    }
}
}
```

Ignore the aItems and the hardware and peripherals classes items that i create they have all been compiled and work fine. But when i compile this class it gives me errors i dont know how to deal with. Please help me.

By the way i must say that i compile through cmd.

Comment: It'll be extremely difficult to guess all the kinds of error you can be doing without you providing how you actually compile it.

Comment: Are you by any chance Greek?!

Comment: Could you please list the compilation errors you are getting?